# Show values with column name in mysqli using php automatically

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to show all row values in my db table with column names dynamically. I am not really getting a point to do that. :(

Here is what I have done so far- it works for around 100K data. but when the row increases, it shows blank screen

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *FROM `master_1m1`");
echo "<table border='1'>";
$i = 0;
$khalid == 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $khalid++;

    if ($i == 0) {
        $i++;
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach ($row as $value) {
        echo "<td>" . $khalid . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: oh! sorry,,, pasting now..

Comment: Can you provide us your php or apache error log file ? You certainly reach max execution time.